# Why is one span thicker than the other although they have the exact same height?

Tags: html, css

I have the following very simple HTML-structure:

2 `span` inside one parent `div`. Both `span` have the exact same height of `1px`. But still one of them looks thicker than the other one. I assume it has to do something with the margin but I don't know what and why.

### EDIT:

Since a lot of people commented that they couldn't see the problem. Here is a screenshot of my view:

[image]

It might be a screen-size- or zooming-problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="parent">
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not seeing any difference

Comment: They are both 1px high as you can see 2 black lines, the grey is the margin of the first span.

Comment: do you have any zoom activated?

Comment: I’m seeing it, in a current Chrome. If I increase the margin pixel by pixel using dev tools, then I can see the effect come and go. Probably an issue with sub-pixel rendering or something like that.

Comment: The problem is in anti-aliasing. Although size in CSS is the same,  sometimes, sizes on-screen of small elements (1-2px) can visually look different.

Comment: There is no zoom activated.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the `margin` to see it.

all `span` are equal why you were seeing the upper `span` is smaller that the lower one is because the upper were closer to upper edge which made it looks some how small.

### The following is an example

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want to achieve ?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  flex: 0 0 1px;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}

span + span {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="parent">
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```